LOESS Curve Smoothing In Google Sheet
Hi I'm trying to create a LOESS Curve Smoothing function in google sheet, based on a Excel VBA function
With the help of ChatGPT I was able to convert VBA to GAS, however, I'm getting the following error:
Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
LOESSsub    @ Code.gs:107
generateSumIfFormula    @ Code.gs:32
Can someone help to figure this out
Here's the Google Sheet where the function is already added to GAS:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A0K8pmCqO8UO17DQhz3NHZ-EDU1NOohBlYWyIrNsdK0/edit?usp=sharing
